# What should I do with questions with broken images?

Tags: discussion, images

Here is an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754658/what-is-the-simplest-method-to-fill-the-area-under-a-geom-freqpoly-line), where the author originally uploaded the image to imageshack, which is no longer operating as a free image host as we know it.

In the event that the old image cannot be recovered and the placeholder image holds no relevance to the question, yet the question makes references to said image(s), what would be the most appropriate course of action?

I am thinking that removing the images is the best solution, but that means users who come across this question hereon will think it is a badly-formatted question (and perhaps flag it for low quality?) because of the missing referenced images.

Comment: I'd VTC them as "unclear what you are asking" and leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the images are used. The specific question you references is understandable without images: the OP wants to have a plot like `geom_freqpoly`, but with a filled-in area; and `geom_density` (which provides filled-in area) does not work for them because of built-in smoothing.

Removing the images and references to them would solve the issue. Fortunately, this wasn't necessary, because the images were preserved by Internet Archive; I restored them.

In other cases, a question may be truly incomprehensible without images. If the OP is still around, commenting *might* help in getting replacement images from them. If all else fails, the question will end up closed as unclear, and then deleted.